# Editable DataGridView bound to a List

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a DataGridView bound to a list. The values show fine, when I click on a value, it starts editing, however when I press Enter, the change is ignored, no data are ever changed. When I place a breakpoint in the Value setter, I can see it is executed after the edit, but no changed data are ever shown. My binding code looks like this:

```
namespace DataGridViewList
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public struct LocationEdit
    {
      public string Key { get; set; }
      private string _value;
      public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
    };

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      BindingList<LocationEdit> list = new BindingList<LocationEdit>();
      list.Add(new LocationEdit { Key = "0", Value = "Home" });
      list.Add(new LocationEdit { Key = "1", Value = "Work" });
      dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
    }
  }
}
```

The project is a basic Windows Forms project, with a DataGrid created in a designer, with columns called Key and Value and set DataPropertyName to Key / Value respectively. No values are set to Read Only.

Is there some step I am missing? Do I need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or something else?

Comment: Could you show some more code? Like, for example, the Edit/Confirm  event handler?

Comment: @PiotrJustyna I have no such handler. Do I have to add one?

Comment: What's happening is your datagrid knows nothing about the change in the underlying list. Every time you change the value, please notify the grid using for example ResetBindings method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resetbindings.aspx).

Comment: I see you updated your question and instead of *List<T>* you're using *BindingList<T>*. In this case, please take a look at this ResetBindings method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132702.aspx.

Comment: @PiotrJustyna How do I know the value was changed? I have tried added ResetBindings to CurrentCellChanged, the event is triggering, but there is still no change visible. The behaviour I see with List and BindingList is the same.

Comment: Please try to subscribe to *CellEndEdit* event and then call *ResetBindings* on your *BindingList*. Your next problem is that you will have to get the instance of your *BindingList* somehow. Please consider making it a private field in your class.

Comment: @PiotrJustyna I did that, still see no change: dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += dataGridView1_Reset; private void dataGridView1_Reset(object sender, EventArgs e) {_list.ResetBindings();} There must be something obvious I am missing, but I really have no idea what.

Comment: That's strange indeed. Are you sure you posted all your code? What happens if you manually change your current row? (just like in this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your are using a `struct` as the BindingList item type. The solution is you should change `struct` to `class` and it works GREAT. However if you want to keep using `struct`, I have an idea to make it works, of course it requires more code than simply changing `struct` to `class`. The whole idea is every time a cell has its value changed, the underlying item (which is a struct) should be assigned to a totally new struct item. That's the only way you can use to change the underlying value, otherwise the cell value after committing change won't be changed. I've found that the event `CellParsing` is the one suitable for this case to add custom code, and here is my code:

```
namespace DataGridViewList
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
     public struct LocationEdit
     {
       public string Key { get; set; }
       private string _value;
       public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
     };

     public Form1()
     {
       InitializeComponent();
       BindingList<LocationEdit> list = new BindingList<LocationEdit>();
       list.Add(new LocationEdit { Key = "0", Value = "Home" });
       list.Add(new LocationEdit { Key = "1", Value = "Work" });
       dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
     }
     //CellParsing event handler for dataGridView1
     private void dataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e){
        LocationEdit current = ((BindingList<LocationEdit>)dataGridView1.DataSource)[e.RowIndex];
        string key = current.Key;
        string value = current.Value;
        string cellValue = e.Value.ToString()
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) key = cellValue;
        else value = cellValue;
        ((BindingList<LocationEdit>)dataGridView1.DataSource)[e.RowIndex] = new LocationEdit {Key = key, Value = value};
     }
   }
}
```

I don't think it's a good idea to keep using `struct` that way, `class` would be better.