# How to make DataGridView editable in WinForms when DataSource is LIst<'a>

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I can do the following but it creates my DataGridView as Readonly.

```
var entries = (from e in dbContext.Entries
 where e.FromWord == "test"
  select new {
    EntryID = e.EntryID,
    WordClass = e.WordClass,
    Plural = e.Plural,
    FromWord = e.FromWord,
    LettersOnly = e.LettersOnly,
    Notes = e.notes
  }
).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = entries;
```

How do I make the DataGridView editable?

If I remove the ToList() I get an error that says I have to use a DataSet as the DataSource. Is there an easy way to create a DataSet. I'm using Entity-Framework with Database-First.

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808590/editable-datagridview-bound-to-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

@Nobody, in the comment above, has helped me answer my question with this link [Editable DataGridView bound to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808590/editable-datagridview-bound-to-a-list)

I created this model class:

```
  public class RowEntry
  {
    public int EntryID {get; set;}
    public string WordClass {get; set;}
    public bool Plural {get; set;}
    public string FromWord {get; set;}
    public string LettersOnly {get; set;}
    public string Notes { get; set; }
  }
```

And then simply changed the linq query to this - removing the anonymous class:

```
List<RowEntry> entries = (from e in dbContext.Entries
     where e.FromWord == "test"
      select new RowEntry {
        EntryID = e.EntryID,
        WordClass = e.WordClass,
        Plural = e.Plural,
        FromWord = e.FromWord,
        LettersOnly = e.LettersOnly,
        Notes = e.notes
      }
    ).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = entries;
```

DataGridView is now editable. I'm guessing the scope the anonymous List type is too limited to be editable by the DataGridView class.